# How to pass trough all nodes and put the element values in a class separately

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

So, i'm newbie in XML, and i'm trying to create some lists of codes that will be pulled from an xml file.

Each Node with 'ParentId' ==  -1 have some related nodes to it. And every Node have four cells with different values, who i need to put in a Class "Campo". That way, each field generate a list who i use to fill some controls.

I'm trying to solve this with Linq, and so far i figured out how get the sucessors and the predecessors fields. The problem is that I can't get the four cells separately, on correspondent parameter of the class "Campo". The code only return the first element ("Cell"), for all Class parameters.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**This is the xml structure:**

```
<TreeList>
<Nodes>
<Node ParentId="-1" Id="0">
<NodeData>
<Cell xsi:type="xsd:string">OBRA</Cell>
<Cell xsi:type="xsd:string">Obra/Cliente</Cell>
<Cell xsi:type="xsd:string">Lista de Itens</Cell>
<Cell xsi:type="xsd:string">4</Cell>
</NodeData>
</Node>
<Node ParentId="0" Id="1">
<NodeData>
<Cell xsi:type="xsd:string">PMG</Cell>
<Cell xsi:type="xsd:string">Presa Monte Grande</Cell>
<Cell xsi:type="xsd:string">Código Fixo</Cell>
<Cell xsi:type="xsd:string">4</Cell>
</NodeData>
</Node>
</Nodes>
</Treelist>
```

**This is what i made so far:**

```
 string caminho = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        string caminhoCompleto = caminho + @"\OBRA.xml";
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(caminhoCompleto);
        List<Campo> codigos = (from codigo in xml.Root.Elements("Nodes").Elements("Node")
                              from node in codigo.Descendants("NodeData")
                              where (int)codigo.Attribute("ParentId") == -1
                              select new Campo
                              {
                                  Codigo = (string)node.Element("Cell").Value,
                                  Descricao = (string)node.Element("Cell").Value,
                                  TipoCampo = (int)node.Element("Cell").Value, //This line return error
                                  NumCarac = (int)node.Element("Cell").Value,
                              }
                        ).ToList();
        foreach (Campo cp in codigos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Field: {0}", cp.Codigo);
            Console.WriteLine("Field: {0}", cp.Descricao);
            Console.WriteLine("Field: {0}", cp.TipoCampo);
            Console.WriteLine("Field: {0}", cp.NumCarac);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();                               
    }
}

class Campo
{
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int TipoCampo { get; set; }
    public int NumCarac { get; set; }
    public List<Campo> Itens;

}
```

**This is the result that I currently have**

```
Field: OBRA
Field: OBRA
Field: OBRA
Field: OBRA
```

**The Result im looking for**

```
Field: OBRA
Field: Obra/Cliente
Field: 3
Field: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right track, if the only issue you're having is with data type conversion - this is one way to approach it: The values are strings, so you can either just [`int.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.8) or [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)

**UPD** so it seems you want all descendants of `<NodeData>` to form you one `Campo` object. You could write another extension method and use it in your query to streamline the way you create the `Campo` objects. See updated code below:

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int TryParseInt(this string value)
    {
        int v = default(int);
        if (int.TryParse(value, out v))
        {
            return v;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("optionally do something on failure");
    }

    public static Campo ParseCells(this XElement node)
    {
        // here I'm able to query for all descendants directly because your source data seems to only have one NodeData for each Node. You could change XPath to suit your actual case
        var cells = node.XPathSelectElements("NodeData/Cell").ToArray();
        return new Campo
        {
            Codigo = (string)cells[0].Value,
            Descricao = (string)cells[1].Value,
            TipoCampo = int.Parse(cells[2].Value), //either do int.Parse
            NumCarac = cells[3].Value.TryParseInt(), // or opt for int.TryParse through a convenience extension method
        };
    }
}
void Main()
{
    string caminho = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    //string caminhoCompleto = caminho + @"\OBRA.xml";
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse("<TreeList><Nodes><Node ParentId=\"-1\" Id=\"0\"><NodeData><Cell >OBRA</Cell><Cell >Obra/Cliente</Cell><Cell >Lista de Itens</Cell><Cell >4</Cell></NodeData></Node><Node ParentId=\"0\" Id=\"1\"><NodeData><Cell >PMG</Cell><Cell >Presa Monte Grande</Cell><Cell >Código Fixo</Cell><Cell >4</Cell></NodeData></Node></Nodes></TreeList>");
    var codigos = (from codigo in xml.Root.Elements("Nodes").Elements("Node")                                                  
                           where (int)codigo.Attribute("ParentId") == -1                           
                           select codigo.ParseCells() // not that ParseCells takes care of object creation for us - we can simplify the LINQ and remove extra nesting here
                    ).ToList();
    foreach (Campo cp in codigos)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Field: {0}", cp.Codigo);
        Console.WriteLine("Field: {0}", cp.Descricao);
        Console.WriteLine("Field: {0}", cp.TipoCampo);
        Console.WriteLine("Field: {0}", cp.NumCarac);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}


public class Campo
{
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int TipoCampo { get; set; }
    public int NumCarac { get; set; }
    public List<Campo> Itens;
}
```

A side note: I believe your source fields and the code are out of sync, as `TipoCampo` should be int, but source data has a string in there.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In fact, the problem i'm pass trough its because, i looking for  get the four cells, separately, but the code only give me the first XElement("Cell").

For example, the idea its see sometime like this:
```Field 1: OBRA
Field 2: Description
Field 3: Type:
Field 4: Characters Numbers
```
But the result im geting in this code is:

```
Field 1: OBRA
Field 2: OBRA
Field 3: OBRA
Field 4: OBRA
```

Comment: just updated the answer thinking you probably want more then just type coercion :)

Comment: yes, definitely see the update - does it help with what you're after?

Comment: Thank you, you understand what I'm going through. I'll try your method and come back later to say if it worked. :)

Comment: You are my hero. It works like a charm. I can go through all the nodes on a list. So now I can get all the parameters I want in order. Thanks man.